# calculate two values on fly with javascript / jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have two controls, textbox and dropdown, I want to calculate the sum of those two fields on asp button click.
This is what I have:
Dropdown Value

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" Width="74px">
  <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="9" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="11" Value="11" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="12" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="13" Value="13" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

TextBox Value

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" CssClass="input-mini" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Calculate Sum" CssClass="btn btn-minibtn-info" />
Textbox Result <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" CssClass="input-mini" />
```

I want on button click to calculate the sum of the dropdown + textbox9 and then put the value in TextBox10.
Any idea how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register to client click:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="return ButtonClick();" ... />
```

JS:

```
function ButtonClick() {
    var ddlVal = parseInt($('#<%=DropDownList3.ClientID%>').val());
    var tb9Val = parseInt($('#<%=TextBox9.ClientID%>').val());
    $('#<%=TextBox10.ClientID%>').val(ddlVal + tb9Val);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need the ClientID property in your example? So '#<%=TextBox10.ClientID%>' instead?

Comment: One other thing, I think you'll have to convert the strings into ints via parseInt, otherwise you'll just concatenate the values.

Comment: @A-Dubb Quite right. I wrote it and didn't quality check. Thanks for the corrections!

Comment: No problem. anything I can do to help. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
            $("#<%=Button3.ClientID%>").click(function() {
            var a = parseInt($('#<%=TextBox9.ClientID%>').val());
            var b = parseInt($('#<%=DropDownList3.ClientID%>').val());
            $('#<%=TextBox10.ClientID%>').val(a + b);
            });
        });
```

Comment: You need to be using `"#<%=Button3.ClientID%>"`... etc. See other answer.